# Not sure how to access every value from the firebase database

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to read values from the firebase real-time database. However, as I try to read it, I end up getting a data structure where I can't access any of the values.

```
  ref.child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let values = Array(data.values)

             for objects in values{
                 print(objects)
            }
        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

The result I'm aiming to achieve is:

```
    39
    -121
    "rhwkfncdnfk"
    1000

    39.583869396
    -125.38589543
    "This is the first message"
    100
```

However in the console the values I'm getting are:

```
    {
        CoordinatesLat = 39;
        CoordinatesLong = "-121";
        Message = rhwkfncdnfk;
        Range = 1000;
   }
   {
        CoordinatesLat = "39.583869396";
        CoordinatesLong = "-125.38589543";
        Message = "This is the first message";
        Range = 100;
   }
```

When I print snapshot.value I am getting:

```
 Optional({
    "2B3BF5F1-E9DF-4292-9278-15B8C5849C15" =     {
        CoordinatesLat = "39.583869396";
        CoordinatesLong = "-125.38589543";
        Message = "This is the first message";
        Range = 100;
    };
     "7C000DB1-EA91-4129-B944-A0A09E6D24C7" =     {
        CoordinatesLat = 39;
        CoordinatesLong = "-121";
        Message = rhwkfncdnfk;
        Range = 1000;
    };
})
```

I'm not sure how to parse what is being printed out and get the actual values.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `.value` Firebase returns the value of the underlying node/property in the type that you've stored. So your `Message` will be returned as a string, the `Range` as a number and the latitude and longitude as strings (because that's how you stored them).

```
ref.child("messages").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    print(snapshot.childrenCount); // prints the number of messages

    for message in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        print(message.key); // "2B3BF5F1-E9DF-4292-9278-15B8C5849C1"

        print(message.childSnapshot(forPath: "Message").value); "This is the first message"
        print(message.childSnapshot(forPath: "Range").value); 100

    }

}) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```